# Error using makefile to convert to topojson: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL]

Tags: makefile, shapefile, topojson

I am following [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bubble-map/) Mike Bostock tutorial for making a bubble map but using a different shapefile and a different dataset.  This is for a class project.  Full disclosure - I am not a programmer and have been just sort of figuring this out as I go along, but I'm totally stuck here, so hopefully someone can help me out.

I created a Makefile to download the shapefile and unzip it in a directory.  That took some figuring out, but not I'm at the point where I want to convert the shapefile to a topojson file.  I am using this command:

```
make build/neighborhoods.json
```

And I'm getting back this error:

```
[SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL]
make: *** [build/neighborhoods.json] Error 1
```

This is after a long list of topojson options.

This seems pretty obvious - I'm making some sort of syntax error.  But I have no idea what it is.

This is my makefile:

```
build/Census_Data.zip:
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    curl -o $@ http://apps.pittsburghpa.gov/dcp/$(notdir $@)

build/Census_Data: build/Census_Data.zip
    unzip -od $(dir $@) $<
    touch $@

build/Neighborhood.shp: build/Neighborhood.zip
    unzip -od $(dir $@) $<
    touch $@

build/neighborhoods.json: build/Neighborhood.shp
    node_modules/.bin/topojson \
        -o $@ \
        --projection='width = 960, height = 600, d3.geo.albersUsa() \
            #.scale(1280) \
            #.translate([width / 2, height / 2])' \
        --simplify=.5 \
        --filter=none \
        --neighborhoods=$<
```

The build directory and the makefile are in the same parent directory.  The shapefile is in the build directory.

If anyone can help me out it would be much appreciated.  Alternately, if anyone can suggest another way of doing this that would be great.  I am also planning to merge the json file with a .csv data file later as Bostock does in the tutorial.  Thanks!

Comment: That's not an error from make. That's an error from topojson. There's something it doesn't like about your input file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is THE answer, but downloading Xcode (I'm usng a mac) solved this.  I recommend downloading it from the apple developer site because it kept stalling out when I tried to download it from the App Store and I read a lot of reports of the same thing happening to others.  Thanks!